# How will broadcast behave with a certain capacity?

Tags: computer-networks

I wanted to confirm something and will appreciate your help. Suppose we have three nodes called A,B and C. All are connected to a switch whose port supports 1 Gbps. Now suppose, Node's A network card is 100 Mbps while the the remaining have a 1 Gbps. Following are the constraints;

1. A can send B only with a maximum of 100 Mbps.
2. A can send C only with a maximum of 80 Mbps.

Now if I were to broadcast a 2 GB file;

1. It would reach B after approx 2.73 minutes.
2. It would reach C after approx 3.41 minutes.

Now even if I replace node A's network card with 1 Gbps with the same constraints, I would still get the same results. Have I got it right?

Comment: If your constraints are independent of A's networking device, than yes. Else, no.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to broadcast from A.

The fastest is probably to broadcast at 80 Mbps and the end of the broadcast is then at 200 seconds (3.33 minutes) for both B and C.

Broadcasting at 100 Mbps will prevent C for receiving your file, since your switch can't store the exceeding 400 MB.

But I don't understand where do your constraints come from? Would it be possible to make C and B communicate? Also I don't quite understand how you did your calculations.